# Regex to separate City and State from input string

Tags: python, regex

I have some input strings.

```
Houston, TX
(Houston, TX)
South & West (Houston, TX)
(South & West (Houston, TX))
```

I am using this pattern but it's not working for all four.

```
.*\(*(.*),\s*(.*)\)*
```

I just want **Houston** and **TX** out of above input strings.

The rules are to take take the stuff out which is inside parenthesis or if there are no parenthesis just the stuff. Resulting list will just have 2 items in it.

Comment: What are the rules here?  Take the stuff in parenthesis if there are parenthesis, otherwise, take the whole line?

Comment: You can't just say "I need a regex to do this" without defining the rules in English.  Tell us what the rules are, and show us the regex you've tried, and then we can help you from there.

Comment: "I just want Houston and TX out of above input strings" was supposed to be a rule.

Comment: @UmairAshraf -- you could have tried `re.findall('Houston, TX',s)` then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the python [Regular Expression operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) page - I found it useful when learning how to do these type of things.

I'm not sure if you wanted to separate out the city & state or not, but you can do so using [groups](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) like so:

```
import re

string = ('Houston, TX ' +
         '(San Francisco, CA) ' +
         'South & West (Houston, TX) ' +
         '(South & West (Houston, TX))')

matches = re.findall("([\w\s]+),\s(\w+)", string)
for match in matches:
    print 'City: ' + match[0] + ', State: ' + match[1]
```

Outputs:

```
City: Houston, State: TX
City: San Francisco, State: CA
City: Houston, State: TX
City: Houston, State: TX
```

Regular Expression:

`([\w\s]+)` Group 1: Matches multiple words with spaces

`,\s` comma followed by a space

`(\w+)` Group 2: Matches a single word

Comment: Sorry but I should also add state may not always of 2 characters there. Would it still work?

Comment: I've modified my answer to handle states with more than 2 characters, and I've explained the regular expression that I'm using.

Comment: Also because I'm not feeding all input at once, is there a find() instead of findall()?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the documentation you will find `re.match`. You may want to have a look at @mgilson's answer as he's provided a function that will do just that. I didn't use `.*` as you have in your attempt because I wanted the regex to be more specific to finding words only - not just any character.

Comment: @UmairAshraf you will have to use the regex: `([\w\s\.]+),\s(\w+)` to include periods inside your matches. Notice I added it into the `[]`, or the set. More information can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: If you use dot (.) in place of \w, how would you write your regex. I just replaced all \w with . and tested but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think that I would do this in 2 steps:

```
in_paren = re.compile(r'(?:\()([^\)\(]+)(?:\))')
match = in_paren.search(ss)
parts = match.group(1) if match else ss
city,state = parts.split(',')
```

Here it is as a function:

```
>>> def find_city_state(ss):
...     match = in_paren.search(ss)
...     parts = match.group(1) if match else ss
...     return [x.strip() for x in parts.split(',')]
... 
>>> for x in ("Houston, TX","(Houston,TX)","South & West (Houston, TX)","(South & West (Houston, TX))"):
...     print find_city_state(x)
... 
['Houston', 'TX']
['Houston', 'TX']
['Houston', 'TX']
['Houston', 'TX']
```

Comment: I added fourth input string.

Comment: @UmairAshraf -- I modified my regex to handle it.  Now, my regex only takes the innermost grouping of parenthesis.

Comment: +1 I like your regular expression & the use of `?:` - I didn't even notice other answers till I refreshed the page.

Comment: @TrevorSenior -- I'm not sure if I like it.  Another option would be to just capture the parenthesis as well and slice them off with string slicing.  That might make the regex a little easier to read...Alternatively, I could have used lookahead and lookbehinds instead of non-capturing groups.  I don't know what's best :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> A="Houston, TX (Houston, TX) South & West (Houston, TX) Los Angeles, CA Los Angeles"
>>> re.findall("\w[A-Za-z ]+, [A-Z]{2}",A)
['Houston, TX', 'Houston, TX', 'Houston, TX', 'Los Angeles, CA']
```

`\w` = Will match all names starting with an alphabet

`[A-Za-z ]+` = will match all names with spaces

`, [A-Z]{2}` = will match all abbreviations (Two capital letters)

Comment: Blows up when matching against `Los Angeles, CA`